# Is this possible? Google Analytics access

Tags: google-analytics

A client granted me access to their Google Analytics. I need to share it with my contractor however I don't want them to access my Gmail. How can I provide them my login for Analytics and restrict them from accessing my Gmail.

(I'm trying to not bother the client and I don't have the right privileges to add another user to their Google Analytics account)

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Is the client aware of your contractor, or are you trying to keep them out of the picture?

Answer (score 0):

## It's a Pickle

Straight from the get-go, I feel you. I've been in similar situations multiple times. It's a pickle of a situation. However, I think there is a good solution for you:

***Ask your client for administrator access.***

Now hold up! This may seem like something that will bother them, but it's something that will allow you to do the work you need to do. They want you to do a good job and have the tools to do it, and having admin access will allow for that. You wisely, do not want to share your login credentials with your contractor.

### Reasoning

Having said that, it is my natural inclination to not ask a client to do work. It feels like an inconvenience to them, that they're paying me to do the work, and that they aren't paying me for them to do work. However, I've been training myself to think differently about that. I've been trying to reframe the relationship between us and clients like it's a *partnership*, that we're on the same team, and that we're *both going to have to do work* to see the project through to completion. I need to be able to ask the client to do work, like set up accounts, provide content, review edits etc. It's furthermore an exercise in trust. If they don't trust you enough to grant you admin access, it's your job to help them see that they need to trust you in order for you to do great work for them.

***And they want you to do great work.***

### Strategy

I generally have my clients give me administrator access to all accounts that I need to manage. That way I can make any changes needed to the account and add users etc. I would have ran into a similar problem earlier today (the client granted me access to their Analytics account with my individual business email, instead of our joint email account that we use for those kind of activities). However, since I had asked them to give me administrator access, I was able to add our joint account as a user and remove my individual account.

Specifically in your situation, I would not recommend sharing your login information with a contractor. I think that is the only way of getting around getting admin access to their Analytics account.

I hope that helps you navigate that situation! Try to ***reframe the problem as an opportunity for some practice to ask your client to do something.*** It may seem be hard, but it will help so much in this situation, and for other situations where having the client do a bit of work will make your work and the project so much better.

**You've totally got it!**

Answer (score 0):

If you give access to your Google Account to the contractor, of course it will also see Gmail.

Solutions:

- Ask for access for the contractor;
- Create a dashboard that reads data with Google Analytics API and share that with the contractor.